# UIImage's resizableImageWithCapInsets brings multiple CoreGraphics "invalid context 0x0" errors under iOS 7

Tags: uiimage, ios7, core-graphics

I've just noticed this issue with `resizableImageWithCapInsets` under iOS 7. Suddenly, I'm getting this error logs, but my app isn't crashing:

```
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Oct 28 14:35:15 <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

And this is the code that's producing the error:

```
[_registerButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets){15, 15, 15, 15}]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If I comment the line above, the error disappears. Has someone else experienced this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the issue. The "image.png" file was 30 pixels tall, so with top and bottom edgeInsets at 15, there was no empty space vertically speaking. It was working visually, but I was recieving those errors. I hope this will be useful for others.